# How to create a PDO query for fetch with variables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to build a PDO query for a large project to fetch SQL fetch queries. These SQL queries use variables to get values. I can't use the ones I get in the tutorials - I don't understand how to modify them to be able to use variables instead of `:id` for example. I have many many many files to update to PDO, because currently they are written using `mysql()`

An example of the query (one in of hundreds of files):

```
if(!$GLOBALS['this_brand']->id) return false;
if(!$GLOBALS['url_lang']) return false;
if(!$GLOBALS['this_region']->id) return false;
if(!$GLOBALS['this_type']->id) return false;
if(!$GLOBALS['this_user']->group) return false;     

if(!$liveid = $GLOBALS['this_config']->get('config_live_id')) return false;         
if(!$draftid = $GLOBALS['this_config']->get('config_draft_id')) return false;   
if(!$archiveid = $GLOBALS['this_config']->get('config_archive_id')) return false;

if($GLOBALS['this_user']->is_admin()) {
      $statussql = "AND (page.status = ".$liveid." OR page.status = ".$draftid." OR page.status = ".$archiveid.")";
    }
else {
     $statussql = "AND page.status = ".$liveid;
 }

$the_statement = "SELECT * FROM page
LEFT JOIN _page_brand ON page.id = _page_brand.page_id
LEFT JOIN _page_language ON page.id = _page_language.page_id
LEFT JOIN _page_region ON page.id = _page_region.page_id
LEFT JOIN _page_type ON page.id = _page_type.page_id                        
LEFT JOIN _page_group ON page.id = _page_group.page_id                      

LEFT JOIN _page_section ON page.id = _page_section.page_id                      

WHERE _page_brand.brand_id = ".$GLOBALS['this_brand']->id."
AND _page_language.language_iso = '".$GLOBALS['url_lang']."' 
AND _page_region.region_id = ".$GLOBALS['this_region']->id."
AND _page_type.type_id = ".$GLOBALS['this_type']->id."
AND _page_group.group_id = ".$GLOBALS['this_user']->group."

AND _page_section.section_id = ".$GLOBALS['this_section']->id."

".$statussql." 
AND page.url = '".$this->url."' 
ORDER BY page.status ASC, page.moddate DESC
LIMIT 1";
```

My PDO attempt (it looks really lame but I did try different ways, but removed the code once they didn't work):

```
public function fetchRaw($query){

    $stmt = $this->db->query($query);
    $arr = [];

    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
        $rarr = [];
        foreach($row as $k=>$v) {
            $rarr[$k] = $v; 

        }
        $arr[] = $rarr;
    }

    return $arr;

}
```

I tried with the `fetch()`, the `while` loop etc. I cannot go and change each current query - there are thousands of them. Any help on how this should be approached will be appreciated. I am not an expert on PDO yet, and this huge project is a bit overwhelming, but I need to do this.

Comment: are you trying to automate refactoring all your code, or are you trying to use a function which will run each query somehow?  I think either way you need to resign yourself to some laborious manual input as you will need to check each function and confirm it still works

Comment: What I'm really asking is, how/where are you planning to call fetchRaw() and what are you going to pass to it, and what do you want the output to be

Comment: Hi @jameson2012, I want to write the function so that when it is called on another file with many methods consisting of several `SELECT` statements using `GLOBALS['pdodatabse']->fetchRaw` for example. I want to then have the query processed. It seems to work for basic `SELECT` queries, and I tested on a few where the values are stored in variables and it worked, but for some reason it does not work with the large queries.

Comment: but @Horcrux , you wouldn't be using prepared statements if you did this.  Prepared statements are supposed to prepare a statement, using place markers, and then safely bind the values at execution - I guess you're hoping to have in your file a line like ````fetchRaw($thisStatement)```` so you can just put this into each file instead of paramatizing each statement, yes?  In your function you need to use different pdo fetch methods (fetch(),fetchAll() etc) to get the different responses you require (single result, single column, full result set) so....

Comment: ... your function would be incredibly complicated, but you wouldn't achieve anything because you would still be passing raw variables straight into your sql anyway, because you need to re-write the query to have a placemarker and a corresponding value, so I don't think this will help you in any way, except to pretend you are using pdo

Comment: this might give you some ideas https://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/9199/post/3-Smoothly-Migrate-your-PHP-Code-using-the-Old-MySQL-extension-to-MySQLi.html

Comment: @jameson2012, it makes sense what you are saying, thanks. What do you mean by "pretend to use pdo" though?

Comment: I just mean that by sending the raw query to the pdo object, but not binding your variables at all ($pdo->bindParam(...)) you would make it look like you're using PDO but really you're just doing the same unsecured query so you'd still 100% open to sql injection as you're just passing variables straight in